# connecting to secure website using CmisClient library

Tags: python, ssl, https, cmis

In my project we are trying to use CMIS to get the folder repository and I use python script to test it; below is the piece of code I used

```
from cmislib.model import CmisClient
client = CmisClient('http://localhost/CMIS/Service/servicedoc', 's', 's')
repo = client.defaultRepository
info = repo.info
for k,v in info.items():
    print "%s:%s" % (k,v)

somefld = repo.getObject('idf_96_Z2CMIS')      
props = somefld.properties
for k,v in props.items():
    print "%s:%s" % (k,v)
```

This code works perfectly fine. However now the service is SSL enabled so (https//localhost/CMIS/Service/servicedoc) when I change the URL in CmisClient it is throwing the below error

```
c:\Python27>python.exe cmis.py
CMIS client connection to https://localhost/Cmis/Service/servicedoc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmis.py", line 4, in <module>
    repo = client.defaultRepository
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cmislib-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\cmislib\model.py",
 line 179, in getDefaultRepository
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cmislib-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\cmislib\model.py",
 line 206, in get
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cmislib-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\cmislib\net.py", l
ine 145, in get
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

How do I use CMISClient library to connect to SSL enabled website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that https URL work in your browser without errors?

Comment: Yes. It works. Just wanted to know how to I call the SSL enabled site using cmisClient library

Comment: Can you look in your server logs, and see if it's reporting any SSL connection issues? I wonder if your server and python can't agree on a suitable set of SSL connection options

Comment: I saw it under Windows logs in Event viewer and there is no error. Do you say that my code above should work by just changing the URL to https

Comment: I changed my URL to have the <<machinename>> instead of localhost https://<<MachineName>>/Cmis/Service/servicedoc and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my URL to have the <> instead of localhost https://<>/Cmis/Service/servicedoc and it worked.